# Apache URL Rewrite query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I would like to rewrite this URL :

```
https://example.com/super/index.php?route=doo/math&user_token=AxDJFKDLS73jfd
```

Into this URL :

```
https://example.com/super/math&user_token=AxDJFKDLS73jfd
```

Or even this one :

```
https://example.com/super/user_token=AxDJFKDLS73jfd
```

I have tried differents methods by modifying the .htaccess in the /super directory and adding :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^super/$ index.php?route=doo/math [L]
```

Also tried that :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=doo/math([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1?%2 [R,L]
```

Also by adding directly in apache vhost :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&route=([0-9]{10,12})(?:&)(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/super/$1?%1/%2\?%3 [NE,L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, none of the methods are working, help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and applies to `https://example.com/super/user_token=AxDJFKDLS73jfd`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^super/user_token\=(.*)$ /index.php?route=doo/math&user_token=$1 [L]
```

Edit:

Or you can even use this

```
RewriteRule ^super/user_token\=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?route=doo/math&user_token=$1 [L]
```

To match your critieria. A-Za-z0-9